# How to optimize the process of building two graphs in real time based on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, real-time-updates

I'm trying to resolve a task of realtime plotting from pandas DataFrame. The main task is to create a realtime graph from input timeframe based on realtime updating base.
At first I tried to solve a task with only one real-time graph and completely done it. It works well with small and big timeframes. Next I have decided to make two graphs into one figure. So, I've done it, but it works really slower in small timeframes (etc 1 sec).
If anybody have an ideas to resolve my problem I will be really appreciative.

I saw this topics and tried to combine the best answers but it didn't help me:

1) [realtime plotting pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909063/realtime-plotting-pandas-dataframe)

2) [How to return an unknown number of objects in Python animation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520032/how-to-return-an-unknown-number-of-objects-in-python-animation-function)

3) [animated subplots using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832055/animated-subplots-using-matplotlib)

```
First code variant without FuncAnimation

import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def plots(exchange, pair, timeframe):
    points_amount = 24
    database = exchange + '_' + pair + '.csv'

    plt.ion()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(12,5))
    plt.tight_layout()

    while True:
        df = pd.read_csv('{}'.format(database))
        our_df = df.copy()
        our_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(our_df['Date'])
        our_df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)  # try to delete inplace

        timeframe_df = our_df.resample('{}S'.format(timeframe)).agg(
            {'Price': lambda s: s.mean(),
             'Quantity': lambda s: s.mean()
             }
        )

        timeframe_df = timeframe_df[-200:]

        dframe = timeframe_df.copy()

        current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_time = pd.to_datetime(current_time)
        delta_time = pd.Timedelta(seconds=timeframe * points_amount)
        past_time_limit = current_time - delta_time

        dframe = dframe.loc[timeframe_df.index > past_time_limit]

        #timelim = pd.Timedelta(seconds=timeframe * points_amount)
        #xlim_left = df.index.max() - timelim
        #ax[0].set_xlim(xlim_left, df.index.max())
        #ax[1].set_xlim(xlim_left, timeframe_df.index.max())

        ax[0].clear()
        ax[1].clear()
        #ax[0].figure.canvas.draw()
        #ax[1].figure.canvas.draw()

        ax[0].set_title('Price')
        ax[1].set_title('Quantity')

        ax[0].plot(dframe.index, dframe['Price'])
        ax[1].plot(dframe.index, dframe['Quantity'])

        plt.pause(timeframe)


An example of my code with FuncAnimation

def plots(exchange, pair, timeframe):
    """Create a real-time updated graph from database values"""

    # Number of points displayed on the chart
    points_amount = 24
    database = exchange + '_' + pair + '.csv'

    if not os.path.isfile(database):
        time.sleep(timeframe)
        plotter(exchange, pair, timeframe)


    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 5))

    def graphs_plotter(self):
        """Update graphs' parameters"""

        # Reading database and import it to pandas
        df = pd.read_csv('{}'.format(database))
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
        df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

        # Creating a new timeframe according to input value
        timeframe_df = df.resample('{}S'.format(timeframe)).agg(
            {'Price': lambda s: s.mean(),
             'Quantity': lambda s: s.mean()
             }
        )

        timeframe_df = timeframe_df[-200:]

        current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_time = pd.to_datetime(current_time)
        delta_time = pd.Timedelta(seconds=timeframe * points_amount)
        past_time_limit = current_time - delta_time

        timeframe_df = timeframe_df.loc[timeframe_df.index > past_time_limit]
        timelim = pd.Timedelta(seconds=timeframe * points_amount)
        xlim_left = df.index.max() - timelim

        ax[0].set_xlim(xlim_left, df.index.max())
        ax[1].set_xlim(xlim_left, timeframe_df.index.max())

        ax[0].plot(timeframe_df.index, timeframe_df['Price'])
        ax[1].plot(timeframe_df.index, timeframe_df['Quantity'])

        return ax

    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, graphs_plotter, interval=1000, repeat=False)

    plt.tight_layout()
    ax[0].grid()
    ax[1].grid()
    ax[0].figure.canvas.draw()
    ax[1].figure.canvas.draw()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you consider using `FuncAnimation`, like almost all answers on this topic suggest?

Comment: Yeap, I made a code with FuncAnimation, but unfortunately it doesn't work well. I think it's because mine not optimized code